# XML methods are not allowed in a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a Group By to my simple query XML.
I see a similar question in below link, but I was not able to make it up with mine.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662098/sql-server-xml-methods-are-not-allowed-in-a-group-by-clause)

My sample code

```
DECLARE @xml VARCHAR(8000)  = '<root><que trp=''100001'' ccid=''59748''  /></root>'
DECLARE @recordXml XML = @xml

SELECT
            T.a.value('@trp[1]','CHAR(6)') AS trip_no,
            MAX(T.a.value('@ccid[1]','INT')) AS check_call_id
        FROM @recordXml.nodes('/root/que')T(a)
        WHERE
            LEN(T.a.value('@trp[1]','CHAR(6)')) = 6
            AND ISNUMERIC(T.a.value('@trp[1]','CHAR(6)')) = 1
            AND CONVERT(INT, T.a.value('@trp[1]','CHAR(6)')) > 0
        GROUP BY T.a.value('@trp[1]','CHAR(6)')
```

Any help is appreciated to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sub-query...

```
SELECT
    trip_no,
    MAX(check_call_id)   AS check_call_id
FROM
(
    SELECT
        T.a.value('@trp[1]' , 'CHAR(6)') AS trip_no,
        T.a.value('@ccid[1]', 'INT'    ) AS check_call_id
    FROM
        @recordXml.nodes('/root/que')T(a)
    WHERE
        LEN(T.a.value('@trp[1]','CHAR(6)')) = 6
        AND ISNUMERIC(T.a.value('@trp[1]','CHAR(6)')) = 1
        AND CONVERT(INT, T.a.value('@trp[1]','CHAR(6)')) > 0
)
    AS parsed_xml
GROUP BY
    trip_no
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the best way around to resolve. I appreciate you time!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap the non-aggregated query in a CTE or subquery, and then perform the aggregation on that. For example:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT T.a.value('@trp[1]', 'CHAR(6)') AS trip_no,
            T.a.value('@ccid[1]', 'INT') AS check_call_id
     FROM @recordXml.nodes('/root/que') T(a)
     WHERE LEN(T.a.value('@trp[1]', 'CHAR(6)')) = 6
       AND ISNUMERIC(T.a.value('@trp[1]', 'CHAR(6)')) = 1
       AND CONVERT(int, T.a.value('@trp[1]', 'CHAR(6)')) > 0)
SELECT trip_no,
       MAX(check_call_id)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY trip_no;
```

On a different note, I recommend against `ISNUMERIC` and suggest using `TRY_CONVERT`. `ISNUMERIC` can have some odd behaviour like returning `1` for `ISNUMERIC('.')` but a conversion to any numerical datatype for `'.'` would fail. Also, if the `ISNUMERIC` fails, the following clause `CONVERT(int, T.a.value('@trp[1]', 'CHAR(6)')) > 0` will fail and error. So you can be more concise and do:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT T.a.value('@trp[1]', 'CHAR(6)') AS trip_no,
            T.a.value('@ccid[1]', 'INT') AS check_call_id
     FROM @recordXml.nodes('/root/que') T(a)
     WHERE LEN(T.a.value('@trp[1]', 'CHAR(6)')) = 6
       AND TRY_CONVERT(int,T.a.value('@trp[1]', 'CHAR(6)')) > 0) --If this has decimals, use decimal instead of int
SELECT trip_no,
       MAX(check_call_id) AS check_call_id
FROM CTE
GROUP BY trip_no;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful. I have other join's so I preferred sub query approach by MatBailie. When I am trying implement some of your good points, like using TRY_CONVERT instead of both AND's in my query I am getting an error 'The TRY_CONVERT' function required 3 arguments.' Did it work for you as in your code?

Comment: Yes it did work. `TRY_CONVERT` only needs 2 parameters, although a 3rd can be supplied as a style code, but that is only when working with date and time data types and the `xml` data type; which isn't the case here and it's optional anyway. Was that really the error you received?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @xml VARCHAR(8000)  = '<root><que trp=''100001'' ccid=''59748''  /></root>'
DECLARE @recordXml XML = @xml

SELECT
    dat.trip_no
    , MAX( dat.check_call_id ) AS max_check_call_id
FROM (

    SELECT
        T.a.value( '@trp[1]','CHAR(6)' ) AS trip_no,
        T.a.value( '@ccid[1]','INT' ) AS check_call_id
    FROM @recordXml.nodes( '/root/que' ) T( a )
    WHERE
        LEN( T.a.value('@trp[1]','CHAR(6)') ) = 6
        AND ISNUMERIC( T.a.value( '@trp[1]','CHAR(6)' ) ) = 1
        AND CONVERT( INT, T.a.value( '@trp[1]','CHAR(6)' ) ) > 0

) AS dat
GROUP BY
    dat.trip_no
```

Comment: Thanks for the time..this was helpful!